# Polars python equivalent to glimpse and summary in R

Tags: python, python-polars

I couldn't find a function that would summarize the content in the polars dataframe just like glimpse and summary do it in R?

Comment: Could you explain what glimpse does? What do you expect to get out of a DataFrame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polars has a [describe](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.describe.html?highlight=describe#polars.DataFrame.describe) method:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a': [1.0, 2.8, 3.0],
    'b': [4, 5, 6],
    "c": [True, False, True]
    })

df.describe()
shape: (5, 4)
╭──────────┬───────┬─────┬──────╮
│ describe ┆ a     ┆ b   ┆ c    │
│ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ str      ┆ f64   ┆ f64 ┆ f64  │
╞══════════╪═══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ "mean"   ┆ 2.267 ┆ 5   ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ "std"    ┆ 1.102 ┆ 1   ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ "min"    ┆ 1     ┆ 4   ┆ 0.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ "max"    ┆ 3     ┆ 6   ┆ 1    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ "median" ┆ 2.8   ┆ 5   ┆ null │
```

Which reports, like R's `summary`, descriptive statistics per column. I have not used `glimpse` before, but a quick Google suggests it does something similar to Polar's [head](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.head.html?highlight=head#polars.DataFrame.head), but then with the output stacked vertically, so it is easier to digest when there are many columns.

Comment: Update: I have added glimpse to Polars here: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/5622